# Laravel routing error on clicking a specific link

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes

I have a website built using laravel , on the sidebar menu there is a button called settings which is generating a url . Everything is set on the view and controller but the page is not being redirected to that specific url and instead it just reloads the home page . Can anyone suggest what i might be missing out . Here is the url of my website :- https://admin.surakkhafinserve.com/ultimateloanmanager/public/admin

**Login credentials**:

1. username: admin@gmail.com
2. password: admin

**My Route file**:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'setting'], function () {
    Route::get('data', 'SettingController@index');
    Route::post('update', 'SettingController@update');
    Route::get('update_system', 'SettingController@updateSystem');
});
```

**My Controller file**:

```
public function index()
{

    if (!Sentinel::hasAccess('settings')) {
        Flash::warning("Permission Denied");
        return redirect('/');
    }
    $sms_gateways = array();
    foreach (SmsGateway::all() as $key) {
        $sms_gateways[$key->id] = $key->name;
    }
    $countries = array();
    foreach (Country::all() as $key) {
        $countries[$key->id] = $key->name;
    }
    $currencies = array();
    foreach (Currency::all() as $key) {
        $currencies[$key->id] = $key->name;
    }
    $chart_expenses = array();
    foreach (ChartOfAccount::where('account_type', 'expense')->get() as $key) {
        $chart_expenses[$key->id] = $key->name;
    }
    $chart_income = array();
    foreach (ChartOfAccount::where('account_type', 'income')->get() as $key) {
        $chart_income[$key->id] = $key->name;
    }
    $chart_equity = array();
    foreach (ChartOfAccount::where('account_type', 'equity')->get() as $key) {
        $chart_equity[$key->id] = $key->name;
    }
    return view('setting.data',
        compact('sms_gateways', 'countries', 'currencies', 'chart_income', 'chart_expenses', 'chart_equity'));
}
```

Comment: Users aren't likely to want to navigate to your page and login. Can you provide the code of the button in question? We can probably help debug that behaviour with it, but putting a wall (external site, login page, etc) in front of people is a big deterrent to interesting in helping.

Comment: everything is fine.i inspect the element.in settings the link is correct but when i hit that settings link it's redirect me to that dashborad.So you have problem here for redirection.please give your route file & controller

Comment: Looks like your settings are not saving. I checked the admin roles and settings access is there. But the 
` if (!Sentinel::hasAccess('settings')) {
        Flash::warning("Permission Denied");
        return redirect('/');
    }`
 this code is redirecting user back to dashboard

Comment: @mohit so for testing purpose if i remove that condition from the controller then will the redirection work ?

Comment: Yes, it should work

Comment: @mohit i checked the admin roles and on clicking the settings button it should redirect me the settings page but the settings arent getting saved for some reason . I want that to work , is there any work around for this problem?